# Start command inside xterm with login shell, over SSH?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, xterm

I'm trying to use ssh to remotely start an xterm that runs a command inside a non-interactive login environment with a file that sets up the environment that is in a non-standard location. Anybody know how?

Answer (score 1):

There is some missing detail.  But (depending on the variety of ssh client and remote system), you would generally use the `-X` or `-Y` option to get X-forwarding.  The latter is preferred by some, but not necessarily universally available.  [X11Forwarding](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5) (or [ForwardX11](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)) may be disallowed by the remote host's `sshd` daemon. See the [`ssh` manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) for some discussion.

Given that, it sounds as if you have in mind something like

```
ssh -X remotehost xterm -e myshellcommand
```

Like xterm's `-e` option, ssh passes the remainder of the line to the *remotehost* as a command. So there are two levels to work on:

- "xterm -e myshellcommand"
- "myshellcommand"

xterm uses `execv` calls in preference to `system`, so it can accept (properly escaped or quoted) shell separators such as semicolon without assuming that the parameter value for `-e` is quoted as a single token.

Semicolon separates commands in the shell.  For instance, you might do something like this:

```
ssh -X remotehost xterm -e ". extraenvironment; cd anotherdirectory; myshellcommand"
```

You may have to escape the semicolons to make them pass through the different levels, e.g.,

```
ssh -X remotehost xterm -e '. extraenvironment\; cd anotherdirectory\; myshellcommand'
```

In a quick check "here" for instance, I found it necessary to also escape the blanks.  You will probably have to experiment with your configuration to determine what works with your shell (both local and remote).

Comment: So that's close, but it still leaves environment variables unset. Basically, I want to source a .bashrc that isn't in a logical place, so I'll need to specify it. Then, I want all the environment variables set in that .bashrc to apply to the "myshellcommand".